# FIxed storage sized ASCII data type?

Tags: postgresql

I have a database that needs to store UN/LOCODE values and I found out, that using standard data types, it is not possible to store these values in a fixed size form, so that I can play column tetris efficiently.

Currently, I have defined a domain as follows for it:

```sql
-- city: UN/LOCODE https://service.unece.org/trade/locode/Service/LocodeColumn.htm#LOCODE
CREATE DOMAIN t_locode AS VARCHAR
    CONSTRAINT t_locode_check CHECK (
        value IS NULL
        OR
        value ~ '^[A-Z]{2} [A-Z][A-Z0-9]{1,2}$'
);
```

...which results into:

```
testing=# \dT+ t_locode 
List of data types
-[ RECORD 1 ]-----+---------
Schema            | public
Name              | t_locode
Internal name     | t_locode
Size              | var
Elements          | 
Owner             | postgres
Access privileges | 
Description       |
```

I also tried to use a fixed-length character type definition instead of `VARCHAR` (e.g. `CHAR(6)`), but that doesn't change things at all, which I suspect is because the database itself is set to UTF-8, which by definition is a variable-length character encoding.

To further contribute to the issue, this domain is then used in other user data types.

At best, I'd like to define a data type that can store these values using 8 bytes of storage at max, to align with a double.

Does anyone know of a solution for that?

Comment: What exactly is your problem with the domain? And what do you mean by "column tetris"?

Comment: My problem is that it is not fixed-sized on storage, but variable and therefore ends up in the extended storage. However, as I have certain tables using that domain with "NOT NULL", I'd like to get them included into the plain storage for performance and table size reasons (some of the tables will have billions of rows at 10-30 columns).

Comment: By "column tetris" I am referring to the following: https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/on-rocks-and-sand/

Comment: "*ends up in the extended storage*" - not if they are shorter than ~2k

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Do you have some reference for me to read more about that?

Comment: [Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/storage-toast.html#STORAGE-TOAST-ONDISK): "*Out-of-line values are divided into chunks of at most TOAST_MAX_CHUNK_SIZE bytes [...] making it about 2000 bytes*"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String data types are *always* variable width data types in PostgreSQL, no matter if you use `text`, `character varying` or `character`.

I think you are trying to optimize something that does not need optimization. Such attempts often cause more harm than good.

If your strings are always 6 ASCII characters long, they will occupy 7 bytes on storage:

```
CREATE TABLE x(id bigint, t text);

INSERT INTO x VALUES (1, '      '), (2, '000000');

CREATE EXTENSION pageinspect;

SELECT t_ctid, t_attrs FROM heap_page_item_attrs(get_raw_page('x', 0), 'x');

 t_ctid |                   t_attrs                   
--------+---------------------------------------------
 (0,1)  | {"\\x0100000000000000","\\x0f202020202020"}
 (0,2)  | {"\\x0200000000000000","\\x0f303030303030"}
(2 rows)
```

This is a little-endian machine, as you can see from the `bigint` column.

You will notice that the `text` values occupy only 7 bytes each. This is caused by [TOAST](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/storage-toast.html), which is your friend, not your enemy:

> TOAST usurps two bits of the varlena length word (the high-order bits on big-endian machines, the low-order bits on little-endian machines), thereby limiting the logical size of any value of a TOAST-able data type to 1 GB (2<sup>30</sup> - 1 bytes). [...] When the highest-order or lowest-order bit is set, the value has only a single-byte header instead of the normal four-byte header, and the remaining bits of that byte give the total datum size (including length byte) in bytes.

`0x0F` is binary `00001111`: the rightmost `1` says that we have only a single-byte header, and the remaining `0000111` (decimal 7) are the length of the datum, including the header.

Since your values are only 7 bytes long, they will align nicely with `double precision` with only one padding byte lost.

If you want to micro-optimize by avoiding padding bytes, put all string columns next to each other at the end the the table definition. On the other hand, consider than PostgreSQL has to go through the first nine columns to get to the tenth column, so putting frequently used columns first will be a performance benefit.

But I wouldn't worry too much about these issues: saving 4 bytes by using `integer` instead of `bigint` can cause big problems later if you figure out that you need larger numbers, and the placing of columns is irrelevant compared to a good data model, good queries and correct indexes when it comes to performance.

Comment: Thanks a lot for these insights and the example of using native tools to verify what is going on. That will come in handy for me!